# I want MatrixFactor?: Matrix([[2*a, 3*a], [4*a, 5*a]]) → a*Matrix([[2, 3], [4, 5]])

Tags: python, sympy

? how to find common "a"

Matrix all element convert str? I want to find common str "a"

```
from sympy import *
var('a',real=True)
def myMatrixFactor_Str(M):
     # sum=M[0,0]+M[0,1]+M[1,0]+M[1,1]
     # print(sum)
    return M
M=Matrix(2,2,[2*a,3*a,4*a,5*a])     
print("#",                   M )
print("#",myMatrixFactor_Str(M))
# Matrix([[2*a, 3*a], [4*a, 5*a]])
# I want : a*Matrix([[2, 3], [4, 5]])
# I want : "a" + "*" + "Matrix([[2, 3], [4, 5]])"
```

Comment: please explain better what you mean, I have no idea what you are asking